# failing `spec.opts` from Rspec configuration in rails 2.3.18 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-2, rspec1

I have been configuring the Rspec in rails 2.3.18 application with bundler where I done
below stuff,
`ruby -1.8.7`
`gem 'rspec', '1.3.2'`
  `gem 'rspec-rails', '1.3.4'`

When I run the rspec for my simple spec it throws the error with `spec.opts` failed.

I Found below things from `spec.opts`,

`--colour
--format progress
--loadby mtime
--reverse`

Is there any thing I missed from this configuration? Please share your ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I realized that this error came due to the test-unit gem already installed.

I commented test-unit and installed rspec its working fine.

Please share your ideas, Can we use both test-unit && rspec?